# Sharepoint Calendar Color Coding

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar, color-codes

I have used this tutorial to color the events in the calendar based on two scenarios (internal & external): [Color-Code Events on a SharePoint Calendar](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2012/10/color-code-events-on-a-sharepoint-calendar/)

The problem occured in the calendar webpart whereas I cant see all the events that are filled in the events.

Any idea to fix the webpart view..

Answer (score 0):

I've used this same tutorial with much success.
You don't provide too much detail in your question, but as a starting point I would double check this first:

1. Make sure you have "Yes" selected under "Require that this column contains information"
2. Double check that any existing items in the calendar list have the "Category" column filled in - you can do this easily from the data sheet view (as they show in the tutorial) or from Excel or Access. If you had a lot of old entries it would be an easy thing to miss.

If the above doesn't help. Perhaps you can share some more detail of the setup or screen shots so we can figure out what you're missing :-)